# what does mean if a number is placed after "then"

Tags: meaning

Would you mind helping me to figure out the meaning of the following sentence?

> Jason Warnock, then 29, is the man making the life-saving maneuver.
>   "Readers Digest"

I was wondering if ", then 29," means Jason who has 29 years old or something else.

Comment: Yes, "then 29" means he was 29 years old at the time of the life-saving maneuver.

Comment: if only you have posted this as a new post so that I could mark it as a correct answer. Thank you though @Killing Time

Comment: Note that _then_ does not necessarily introduce age. Could be _then a child_ or _then six feet tall_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "then 29" means he was 29 years old at the time of the life-saving maneuver. – [KillingTime](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/141210/killingtime)

Comment: (Doubtless KT submitted this as a 'comment' as it hardly belongs on ELU.)